# How to create a div element out side the selected html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following tag is static element

```
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Image-Morphing-Effect-with-jQuery-Canvas-morphing-js/img/pic.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="">
```

and I want to create a **div tag** around the **img tag** dynamically, like below

```
<div class="dycls">
  <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Image-Morphing-Effect-with-jQuery-Canvas-morphing-js/img/pic.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="">
</div>
```

I tried the below code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Image-Morphing-Effect-with-jQuery-Canvas-morphing-js/img/pic.jpg" height="200" width="200" >


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").prepend("<div class="dycls">");
    $("img").append("</div>");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").wrap('<div class="dycls" />');
});
```

Using prepend()/append() does not work like string concatenation, also they add the passed element as children of the calling element

Answer (score 1):

`prepend/append` will not work in this case. Use [*wrap()*](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

```
var myEl = $('<div />').addClass('dycls');
$('img').wrap(myEl);
```